# Component distribution using EJBs: always treat as last resort?

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

Some former colleague of mine once told me before, remotely distributing EJBs should always be treated as a last resort. According to him, oftentimes, the drawbacks on this implementation outweigh the benefits.

So, when would remotely distributing EJBs be really recommended? what type of situation?

I mean, if I have a web centric app suffering performance degradation because its server cant handle the load, I can have its server load balanced instead.....rather than separate the business component using EJB.

Anyone can enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Not all so simple. EJB technology is the best for applications integrity, based on javaee. Some examples:

1. Remote EJB is simplest way to get access to server business
   functions from remote application (remote client). But now, when
   application clients became more thinner and thinner, role of the
   remote EJBs lost.
2. If your business service spreads among several
       java application, EJB services is simple way (not only one) to
       integrate them together.

Answer (score 0):

Some more background regarding the actual problem might help. I was not able to understand the question completely since it began with EJBs and why or why not should we use them remotely and ended up talking about performance degradation. How are these two related in the context of the problem you are facing ?

Comment: war file deployed in an app server. Performance stars to degrade since server capacity can no longer handle it. Dilemma is: 1) deploy war file in another app server and have them as load balanced or....  2) deploy only business component in another server (by using ejbs)

Comment: IMO, load balancing your application should be the way to go since separating out your logic as remote EJBs involves serious changes to your overall code base. As a side note, directly exposing remote EJBs is not the only approach you have. Even if you choose to deploy your business logic on a dedicated server, you have the choice of using web services (REST or SOAP) endpoints as the entry point to your application and use EJBs behind the scenes. This way, you are not exposing remote EJB interfaces directly but are still able to leverage EJB features. That's just one way of approaching it